# merge array with unique keys

Tags: javascript, algorithm, lodash

I have array of objects called newArray and oldArray.

Like this : `[{name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}]`

```
example : 
newArray = [
{name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
{name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4]}
]

oldArray = [
{name: 'oldArray', label: 'oldArrayLabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
{name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}
]

result will be = [
{name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
{name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4]}, 
{name: 'oldArray', label: 'oldArrayLabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}
];
```

I wanted to merge both the array in such a way that whenever name and label are equal in both the arrays it should only consider newArray value.

I have tried

```
function mergeArrayWithLatestData (newData, oldData) {
  let arr = [];
  let i = 0; let j =0
  while ((i < newData.length) && (j < oldData.length)) {
    if ((findIndex(newData, { name: oldData[i].name, label: oldData[i].label })) !== -1) {
      arr.push(newData[i])
  } else {
    arr.push(newData[i]);
    arr.push(oldData[i]);
  }
  i += 1;
  j += 1;
}
while (i < newData.length) {
    arr.push(newData[i]);
 }
 return arr;
}
```

But i am not getting correct result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected result?

Comment: @InstilledBee Thanks for suggestion . Added example

Comment: What if you have an object that exists in `newArray` but not in `oldArray`, should that be in the final result or not?

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: @ChatterOne yes it should be there in final array.

Comment: What about duplicates in the `newArray` ? Is it possible? Should they be in the final array or should you only have unique values?

Comment: there is no duplicate in newArray .  all objects in newArray has name as unique values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add all array with a check if `name`/`label` pairs have been inserted before with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

```js
var newArray = [{ name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, { name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }],
    oldArray = [{ name: 'oldArray', label: 'oldArrayLabel', values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, { name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }],
    result = [newArray, oldArray].reduce((s => (r, a) => {
        a.forEach(o => {
            var key = [o.name, o.label].join('|');
            if (!s.has(key)) {
                r.push(o);
                s.add(key);
            }
        });
        return r;
    })(new Set), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You should probably specify that this will discard possible duplicates in `newArray`, which may or may not be what was intended.

Comment: @ChatterOne, i think there are no duplicates in single arrays. otherwise it makes no sense to disinguish between new and old data.

Comment: What makes sense to you might not make sense to OP or the other way round. I'm not saying it's wrong, I'm just saying it's good to be explicit about the duplicates being removed using this code.

Comment: @ChatterOne yes there is no duplicate in newArray.

Answer (score 1):

In your first while loop

```
while ((i < newData.length) && (j < oldData.length)) {
  if ((findIndex(newData, { name: oldData[i].name, label: oldData[i].label })) !== -1) 
  {
    arr.push(newData[i])
  } else {
    arr.push(newData[i]);
    arr.push(oldData[i]);
  }
  i += 1;
  j += 1;
}
```

`i` and `j` always have the same value, you are only comparing entries at the same positions in the arrays. If they have different lengths, you stop comparing after the shorter array ends. Your second while-loop will only be executed if `newArray` is larger than `oldArray`.

One possible solution is to copy the `oldArray`, then iterate over `newArray` and check if the same value exists.

```js
function mergeArrayWithLatestData (newData, oldData) {
  let arr = oldData;
  for(let i = 0; i < newData.length; i++) {
    let exists = false;
    for(let j = 0; j < oldData.length; j++) {
      if(newData[i].name === oldData[j].name && newData[i].label === oldData[j].label) {
        exists = true;
        arr[j] = newData[i];
      }
    }
    if(!exists) {
      arr.push(newData[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

var newArray = [
{name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
{name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4]}
]

var oldArray = [
{name: 'oldArray', label: 'oldArrayLabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
{name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}
]

console.log(mergeArrayWithLatestData(newArray, oldArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `Array.reduce()` to create a map of the old Array and group by combination of name and label. Than iterate over all the elements or objects of the new Array and check if the map contains an entry with given key(combination of name and label), if it contains than simply update it values with the values of new array object, else add it to the map. `Object.values()` on the map will give you the desired result.

```js
let newArray = [ {name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4]} ];

let oldArray = [ {name: 'oldArray', label: 'oldArrayLabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, {name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]} ];

let map = oldArray.reduce((a,curr)=>{
  a[curr.name +"_" + curr.label] = curr;
  return a;
},{});

newArray.forEach((o)=> {
  if(map[o.name +"_" + o.label])
    map[o.name +"_" + o.label].values = o.values;
  else
    map[o.name +"_" + o.label] = o;
});
console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Answer (score 1):

You make copies of the original arrays, and in the first one, or change the element, or add:

```
function mergeArrayWithLatestData (a1, a2) {
  var out = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a1))
  var a2copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a2))
  a2copy.forEach(function(ae) {
    var i = out.findIndex(function(e) {
        return ae.name === e.name && ae.label === e.label
    })
    if (i!== -1) {
        out[i] = ae
    } else {
        out.push(ae)
    }
  })
  return out
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/yps8uvf3/ ]

Answer (score 1):

This is Using a classic `filter()` and comparing the name/label storing the different pairs using just `+`. Using destructuring assignment we merge the two arrays keeping the newest first, so when we check the different the newest is always the remaining.

```js
var newArray = [{ name: "abc", label: "abclabel", values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },{ name: "test", label: "testlabel", values: [1, 2, 3, 4] }];

var oldArray = [{ name: "oldArray", label: "oldArrayLabel", values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] },{ name: "test", label: "testlabel", values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }];

var diff = [];

oldArray = [...newArray, ...oldArray].filter(e => {

  if (diff.indexOf(e.name + e.label) == -1) {
    diff.push(e.name + e.label);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; //<--already exist in new Array (the newest)
  }

});

console.log(oldArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object, with key as `name` and `label`. Now, first add all the `oldData` records to the object and then add `newData` records in object. If there are any objects in common with same `name` and `label`, it will overwrite the old Data value. Finally, get the values of the Object which is the merged data set.

```js
var arr1 = [{name: 'def', label: 'abclabel', values: [6,7]}, {name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}];
var arr2 = [{name: 'xy', label: 'abclabel', values: [6,7]}, {name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [6,7]}];

function mergeArrayWithLatestData(newData, oldData) {
  var result = {};
  [...oldData, ...newData].forEach(o => result[o.name + "~~$$^^" + o.label] = o);
  return Object.values(result);
}

let result = mergeArrayWithLatestData(arr1, arr2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: wont works if you have `name: 'ab', label: 'cde'` and `name: 'abc', label: 'de'`. You must create a hash.

Comment: @aloisdg - Agreed. Thank you. Updated

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: using a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) as the initial value in a reducer. You should know that (as in the selected answer) you loose information here, because you're not comparing on the `values` property within the array elements. So one of the objects with name/label pair `test/testlabel` will be lost in the merged `Array`. If concatenation in the snippet was the other way around (so `newArray.concat(oldArray)`, the `test/testLabel Object` within the merged `Array` would contain another `values` property value.

```js
const newArray = [
  {name: 'abc', label: 'abclabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
  {name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4]}
];

const oldArray = [
  {name: 'oldArray', label: 'oldArrayLabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}, 
  {name: 'test', label: 'testlabel', values: [1,2,3,4,5]}
];

const merged = [ 
  ...oldArray.concat(newArray)
      .reduce( (map, value) => 
          map.set(`${value.name}${value.label}`, value), 
          new Map())
  .values()
];
  
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mergeArray(newArray, oldArray) {
      var tempArray = newArray;

      oldArray.forEach(oldData => {
        var isExist = tempArray.findIndex(function (newData) {
          return oldData.name === newData.name;
        });
        if (isExist == -1) {
          tempArray.push(oldData);
        }
      });

      return tempArray;
    }

    var newArray = [{
      name: 'abc',
      label: 'abclabel',
      values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, {
      name: 'test',
      label: 'testlabel',
      values: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    }];
    var oldArray = [{
      name: 'oldArray',
      label: 'oldArrayLabel',
      values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }, {
      name: 'test',
      label: 'testlabel',
      values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }];

    var resultArray = [];
    resultArray = mergeArray(newArray, oldArray);
    console.log(resultArray);
```